# Unable to change location / path settings after migrating Xcode project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, xib

I've migrated an Xcode project (iOS app) from one mac to another (same Dev Account and Code Signing preferences). Now the build fails and I get errors stating that certain files (MainWindow.xib, MyappViewController.xib and InfoPlist.string) don't exist. I've already read that several people have had this problem before and tried out the answers they got, but nothing seems to work.

As I understand, the problem lies within the path preferences for the NIB files. The error messages give the files' path as Users/Meonmyoldmac/etc - which I should change, because it's an absolute path and therefore doesn't make sense on another computer. But: when I try to open those files under Groups & Files their location is already set to 'Relative to group' and their path is given as Users/Meonmynewmac/etc. - which is exactly how I actually want it to be. (Oddly enough, the file type is listed as 'Default - Unknown' )

I've already tried… 
- cleaning the project
- deleting those files from the project and putting them back in again
- restarting Xcode several times

that's possibly important:
- I'm talking about a Universal iOS App, yet only iPhone files are affected; their iPad equivalents work fine
- I changed the app localization to German, so the mentioned files are located in a folder called de.lproj
- I created the project with Xcode 4 on my older Snow Leopard Mac and use Lion/Xcode 4.2 on the new one - does that play any role here?

Thanks in advance, Fruity

Answer (score 3):

If you have absolute paths to some of your files, you'll need to change them to relative paths:

1. In the `Project Navigator`, locate the missing files (colored red for not being found) and highlight one of them.
2. Show the `File Inspector`
3. Under `Location` change `Absolute Path` to `Relative to group` or `Relative to project`,
4. Then next to the path, there's a little white icon, click it and choose the file's location.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the files in Finder, select `Get Info`.  Check that you have permission to read the files.

**Edit**: Just noticed the error messages refer to the old path, so it can't be a permissions problem.

Groups can have paths set as well.  Select the groups and verify that their paths are correct.

Comment: I just realised that.  Check my edit for another possibility.

Comment: The group paths are also entered correctly (relative, new Mac). Still, when I try to build, I receive error messages displaying another, wrong path (absolute, old Mac). Is this some kind of Xcode Personality Disorder?!

Comment: Open Terminal, `cd /Users/Menonmynewmac/etc` and run `grep -ri Meonmyoldmac .`.  Hopefully that search will ferret out which files or settings are responsible.

Comment: "Groups can have paths set as well. Select the groups and verify that their paths are correct." Thanks! Here was my problem. For files in group you also can choose "relative to project" location instead of "relative to group".

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4, when you have all three panes open, select the file in the left most pane.  In the right most pane, select the white document icon at the top, looking for the header "Identity and Type."  Under the popup for "location" is the name of the file.  To the right of that name is a tiny icon like a window.  Click on that, and you can set the location of the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that's exactly what I've been doing several times now - still get 'Interface Builder could not open the document "MainWindow.xib" because it does not exist.'

Answer (score 0):

I performed the terminal search suggested by Jim yesterday, found some 'source tree: absolute' entries in project.pbxproj and tried to manipulate them, which didn't work - couldn't even open the project in Xcode afterwards - so I called it a day.

Just now I did what I already tried yesterday before posting my question: I deleted the files from the project and copied them back in again. That miraculously eliminated all red warning signs from my project and just gave me a nice green SIGABRT when I tried to run it on the simulator. Cleaned project, restarted Xcode - perfect. Oh, and I checked the targeted device family setting, found that it was set to iPhone and switched it to iPhone/iPad - no idea if that was part of the issue.

I'm not sure if that's really an answer to the problem - but the problem has vanished...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A less-actions solution. You can change manually in the project definition file.

- Close xCode
- Open .xcodeproj file in a text editor: in fact it's a folder, so edit in a text editor the inside file: project.pbxproj.
- Search for the string:  **absolute** (for sourceTree param)
  For each entry (file with a absolute path set), change **absolute** to **group**.

And change the **path** parameter to a relative path. example:
 path = en.lproj/PilotInfoViewController.xib; 
- Save the file and reopen xCode.

PS: Make a backup copy of your project file before doing this manipulation.